# Group by on the basis of conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, group-by

I have a table:

```
spent  totalsent  totalused
----------------------------
4      1234       123
6      12         4
7      45         32
```

I need to group totalused/totalsent in groups of 0 <= spent <= 5, 6 <= spent <= 10 and so on.

How can this be done?

Comment: i just want group by on the basis of conditions on an attribute. Here it is (totalsent/totalused) grouped by spent in groups of 0-5, 6-10, 11-15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just wanting groups of 5, you can probably just set up a column to group on which divides by 5.

```
with my_source_data as (
  select 4 as spent, 1234 as totalsent, 123 as totalused from dual union all
  select 6 as spent, 12 as totalsent, 4 as totalused from dual union all
  select 7 as spent, 45 as totalsent, 32 as totalused from dual
)
select 
  (spent_group -1) * 5 + 1 as lower_bound, 
  spent_group * 5  as upper_bound, totalsent, totalused 
from (
  select 
    greatest(ceil(spent/5),1) as spent_group, 
    sum(totalsent) as totalsent, sum(totalused) totalused
  from my_source_data  
  group by greatest(ceil(spent/5),1)
)
```

This code doesn't quite handle 0 or anything below 0 correctly since it puts everything in the lower group and labels it `1-5`, but your requirements are a little vague in that respect.

Also, this is a sparse grouping so there will only be a row for 11-15 if there is source data which allows it to be produced.